# Can't remove subview?

Tags: ios, uiview, superview

This is about a web browser.

I have a custom Class that handles the webpages.

```
SNBrowserView
SNBrowserViewPage
```

SNBrowserViewPages have two objects.

```
WKWebView
UIImageView // Snapshot of the WKWebView
```

A function either sustains or recovers a page for memory management.

(Testing) Whenever a page is selected I call a recovery function.

Selection:

```
- (void)browserView:(SNBrowserView *)browserView didSelectPage:(SNBrowserViewPage *)page
{
        if (page.sustained) {

            [page recoverAnimated:NO];
        }
}
```

Sustain:

```
- (void)sustain
{
    _sustained = YES;

    if (_webView) {

        _webView = nil;

        [_webView removeFromSuperview];
    }

    _snapshotView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    _snapshotView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    _snapshotView.image = _snapshot;

    [self addSubview:_snapshotView];
}
```

Recover:

```
- (void)recoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _sustained = NO;

    _webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];

    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    _webView.navigationDelegate = self;

    _webView.UIDelegate = self;

    [self addSubview:_webView];

    [self sendSubviewToBack:_webView];

    [self loadURL:_initialURL]; // Start loading as early as possible.

    if (animated) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^{

                             _snapshotView.alpha = 0.0;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){

                             _snapshotView = nil;

                             [_snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
                         }];
    }
    else {

        _snapshotView = nil;

        [_snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

When I try to recover a page the snapshotView is not set to nil nor is it removed from the superview.

**How is that even possible?**

Even this won't work:

```
- (void)recoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    _snapshotView = nil;

    [_snapshotView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

The snapshotView is a subview, removeFromSuperview should always work, why is there *MORE* to it?

Comment: Could you try to call `[_snapshotView removeFromSuperview]` before calling your `_snapshotView = nil` ?

Comment: I've been doing this mistake over and over again.... It works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try replace all of your

```objective-c
_view = nil;

[_view removeFromSuperview];
```

with

```objective-c
[_view removeFromSuperview];

_view = nil;
```

because what you are doing is setting the `_view` to `nil` and then removing `nil` from superview.